# How to transfer data from one activity to a fragment with Firebase?

Tags: android

Hey I was wondering how I could transfer data from one activity to a fragment using fire base. I have edit text in the activity class and a list view in the Fragment.

I would like to display the information throughout the app database so that other users can see and edit the information too.

Comment: With Firebase??? Lol. I would recommend implementing a [FragmentInteractionListener](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the IDE matters but passing information to a fragment is usually done with fragment arguments. You need to create a static "newInstance" method in your fragment that you can call from the activity and pass whatever info to the fragment through it. Something like this:

```
public static mListFragment newInstance(String fromActivity) {
    mListFragment fragment = new mListFragment ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("STIRNG_FROM_ACTIVITY", fromActivity);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

You can then call the method from the activity like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mListFragment fragment = new mListFragment();
fragment = mListFragment.newInstance("info_to_send");
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments_frame, fragment);
```

From here you can even persist the info across device screen orientation changes..

Answer (score 0):

Just use firebaseRef to setValue() and set the value from the edittext.
Add ValueListener on the fragment to get the same value from dataSnapshot.

:D
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/tree/master/database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart